# upload file using devextreme

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme

i want to add upload document using Dev-Extreme but Getting a error[image]

```js
onFileUpload(event){
     this.file = event.target.files[0]
    }
```

```html
<dxi-column [showInColumnChooser]="false" type="buttons" [width]="100" caption="Upload" cellTemplate="EditTemplate"
          *ngIf="(permissions.updt_in==1)?true:false">
          <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'EditTemplate'">
            <div class="cursor-pointer tblEdtBtn" type="file" (click)="onFileUpload($event)">
              Upload Document
            </div>
          </div>
        </dxi-column>
```

Thanks In advance!!!

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
Getting Errorlike this ..

Answer (score 0):

Use the dx component to achieve upload of a file. Look into the [documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FileUploader/FileSelection/Angular/Light/) and [async upload](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FileUploader/FileUploading/Angular/Light/):  E.g

```
<dx-file-uploader
      selectButtonText="Select photo"
      labelText=""
      accept="image/*"
      uploadMode="useForm"
    >
    </dx-file-uploader>
```